# Searching for strings within a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, istringstream

everyone. I am an experienced C programmer trying to get adjusted to C++. I would like to do the equivalent of this C statement...

```
sscanf(str, "%s %s", sub1, sub2);
```

...but with C++'s string object. Say str is "hello world", doing the above sscanf statement would put "hello" in sub1, and "world" in sub2. I know I can use C functions like that in C++, but I would like to use the C++ string object instead of an array of chars. I've tried this:

```
string q, h, w;
cout << "Type \"hello world\": ";
cin >> q;
istringstream x(q);
x >> h >> w;
if (h == "hello")
    cout << "Yes!\n";
else
    cout << "No!\n";
if (w == "world")
    cout << "Yes!\n";
else
    cout << "No!\n";
```

But it outputs "Yes! No!", which means it picked up the "hello" but not the "world". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the `operator>>` used with `cin` will only capture the "hello" phrase, and will stop at the first delimiter (in this case a space).  If you want to capture the entire input line up to the first line-delimiter typed by the user, you will have to use `getline(cin, q)`.  The two-argument version of `getline()` uses a newline as the delimiter, but there is a three-argument version that allows you to specify a custom line-delimiter character as well.

Comment: And if you had error-checked the stream operation, you would already have caught it there!

Answer (score 3):

Never use iostreams without error checking. As Jason says, read the whole line, not just one token, but even then do check for errors:

```
std::string line;

if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::string h, w;
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    if (iss >> h >> w)
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Error reading your input.\n";
    }
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "Error reading from stdin!\n";
}
```

You can make the `if`s into loops if you want to keep reading.

Basically, you can check every formatted extraction (`getline`, `>>`) as a condition, since the result is convertible to something testable, and the condition will be `false` if the operation failed. Therefore, you must never interpret the purported recipient variables unless the operation succeeded!

Had you added this check to your code `x >> h >> w;`, you would never have made it past that line without failing.